# ef 4.1 LINQ filter an element into a collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using entity framework code first. I have a collection let's say:

```
 IDbSet<A> As {get;set;}
```

A is an object like this:

```
 public class A
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set};
    ....
    public IList<B> Bs {get;set;}
 }
```

and B is:

```
 public clas B
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
 }
```

Using linq I want to filter the As which contains B.name == "something" in its IList so how to achieve this? I am trying to do something like:

```
context.As.Where(a => a.Bs.contains(....));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356089.aspx)

```
context.As.Where(a => a.Bs.Any(b => b.name == "something").ToList();
```

It takes a predicate and returns upon a match making it efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.As.Where(a => a.Bs.Any(x => x.name=="something"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356089.aspx) method.

```
var result = context.As.Where(a => a.Bs.Any(b => b.Name == "something"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you do it like that:

```
var AsWithSomethingBs = 
                    context.As.Where(a => a.Bs.Any(b => b.Name == "Something"));
```

This basically says: give me all the As where any of the A's Bs have a name that is equal to "Something"